# Upgrade to spark 3.4.0 from 3.3.2 gives Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: , although jar is present in the location

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-operator

I have a spark Job that is deployed using k8s and it is of version 3.3.2
Recently there were some vulneabilities in spark 3.3.2

I changed my dockerfile to download 3.4.0 instead of 3.3.2 and also my application jar is built on spark 3.4.0

However while deploying, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: <path>/spark-assembly-1.0.jar
```

where "spark-assembly-1.0.jar" is the jar which contain my spark job.

I have this in deployment.yaml of the app

```
 mainApplicationFile: "local:///<path>/spark-assembly-1.0.jar"
```

and I have not changed anything related to that.  I see that some code has changed in spark 3.4.0 core's source code regarding jar location.

Has it really changed the functionality ? Is there anyone who is facing same issue as me ? Should the path be specified in a different way.

Comment: could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? what is an spark application? you have jobs that you submit? you have an application that use spark-sql? is `spark-assembly` the app you build? I don't think this is the [spark-assembly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-assembly) that you are talking about.

Comment: @GastónSchabas spark application means my spark job . spark-assembly means the jar which I built which contains my spark job. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: the error "**NoSuchFileException: <path>/spark-assembly-1.0.jar**" is the root cause. If you say that you haven't changed anything else than upgrading spark dependency, it doesn't make any sense that the problem now is that your executable jar is not being found. Is that the only error message you are getting? could be that there are previous steps with other errors?

Comment: No thats the only error message I am getting

Comment: I don't think with this level of details someone can guess what is happening. Is there a chance that you show what are your library dependencies? how are you packing your app? the yaml file to deploy your app in k8s? It doesn't make any sense for me that just changing one library dependency you can pack your app in a jar without any error and when you deploy it it says that the packed app doesn't exist

Comment: My app is packaged with a dockerfile and deployed using spark-operator k8s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit this same issue. I believe the behaviour change was introduced in:

> SPARK-43540 - Add working directory into classpath on the driver in K8S cluster mode

Our docker file was overriding the working directory of the base spark image

```
FROM apache/spark:3.4.1@sha256:a1dd2487a97fb5e35c5a5b409e830b501a92919029c62f9a559b13c4f5c50f63 as image
WORKDIR /spark-jars
COPY --from=build /...../target/scala-2.12/my-spark.jar /spark-jars/
```

Changing it to this solved the problem:

```
FROM apache/spark:3.4.1@sha256:a1dd2487a97fb5e35c5a5b409e830b501a92919029c62f9a559b13c4f5c50f63 as image
USER root
RUN mkdir /spark-jars
USER spark
COPY --from=build /...../target/scala-2.12/my-spark.jar /spark-jars/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic @Iain. I also got this resolved similarly . by changing the Jar location. I am marking your answer as accepted

Comment: Just remove 

WORKDIR /spark-jars

works for me